# Print only the first 5 lines of a string

Tags: php, string

I use the conditional statement: `if(count(explode(PHP_EOL, $str) > 5)` to check if the string have more than 5 lines, but how can I print only first 5 lines of the string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use array_slice

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
echo implode(PHP_EOL, array_slice($lines,0,4)) . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

When expolode, put the values into an array. Iterate through an array, and add a counter. When counter is 5, get out from iteration.

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);
$i = 1;
foreach ($lines as $line) {
   echo $line ."\n";
   $i++;
   if ($i >= 5) {
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Whats the problem with the loop? Anyway, yes, `echo $lines[0]; echo $lines[1]; echo $lines[2]; //etc...`

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm late, but you can also limit the results of `explode` to `5`:

```
explode(PHP_EOL, $string, -(count(explode(PHP_EOL, $string )) - 5 ));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
// split lines with new line
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $str);

// loop through first five lines
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $++)
{
   // print line
   echo $lines[$i];
}
```

Comment: This is bad, if there are less than 5 lines you will be in trouble accessing unindexed array elements.